# Remove a suggestion in Content Assist - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, editor

I want to get rid of `strictfp` in Content Assist, so `String` will be the top suggestion. I can't do this through `Java` -> `Type Filters`. I was wondering if there was a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> java -> Editor where you can find the content assist in the top. Change your preferences accordingly.

Comment: But specifically, how would I solve my problem? I can't seem to find the solution in those settings.